# Selenium can't locate xpath of facebook pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to download public images of some facebook pages using xpath. I got the xpath from google chrome dev mode (right click and copy xpath).
The xpath I got is: `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]`

When I try to find it in gogole chrome, it finds the xapth just fine as shown in the image.
[image]

But Selenium throws an exception. 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

The code snippet I am using is as follows-

```
driver.get(page)
sleep(10)

allimgdiv = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]')
```

Comment: Did you sign in first>?

Comment: @arundeepchohan yes I did

Comment: try to create your xpath address (instead of using the chrome) try to use attributes names: example //div[@class="bq4bzpyk"], check if there are some div with id

Answer (score 2):

This expression returns the link of only posted images in an facebook page type: https://www.facebook.com/username/photos

//h2[.//a[contains(@href,"/photos")]]//following::div//img

Try

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[.//a[contains(@href,"/photos")]]//following::div//img')
for image in images:
 linkimage =  image.find_element_by_xpath('./@src').text
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem with facebook is, it contains other images than the page's posted images. I only need the images that the page posted.

Comment: I have changed the xpath expression